# Basic JSON syntax?

Tags: jsonlint, json

Here is part of

```
[
UserJSONImpl{
    "id"=26136358,
    "name"='BryanConnor',
    "screenName"='thewhyaxis',
    "location"='null',
    "description"='TheWhyAxisisacollectionofindepthwritingaboutthevisualizationsthatdeserveyourattention.',
    "isContributorsEnabled"=false,
```

I'm not too familiar with JSON syntax and I haven't found a source on the web that provides an introduction; when I try to parse each JSONObject in the JSONArray I get an error like

```
Expected a ',' or ']' at character 14
```

When I input into jsonlint:

```
Parse error on line 1:

[    UserJSONImpl{      
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']'
```

What's wrong with my JSON?

Comment: Everything. Your code doesn't remotely resemble JSON. See the spec at http://json.org/

Comment: Looks like you're missing a bunch of `'` characters to close your strings. Maybe it's just a formatting error in your code here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[
    {
        "UserJSONImpl": {
            "id": 26136358,
            "name": "BryanConnor",
            "screenName": "thewhyaxis",
            "location": null,
            "description": "TheWhyAxisisacollectionofindepthwritingaboutthevisualizationsthatdeserveyourattention.",
            "isContributorsEnabled": false
            }
    }
]
```

Following http://json.org/

- `[ elements ]` with `elements` as `value`,
- `value` as `object`,
- `object` as `{ members }`,
- `members` as `pair`
- `pair` as `string : value`
- `value` as `object`
- ...

Comment: Just to clarify: should all UserJSONImpl{..., StatusJSONImpl{...., etc be in the format "UserJSONImpl": {...., or is it at the beginning of each JSONObject?

Comment: all objects must be `{ members }` (or `{}`), which is a single `string : value` or a list of (`string : value, string : value...`. `string` is `"chars..."`. So for a list of objects, you would have something like `[{"obj1": {"key1": val1, "key2": val2}}, {"obj2": {"key3": val3, "key4": val4},...}]`, `valx` being `"string"` or integer    or boolean, or array `[...]` etc.