# Foreach array inside of array

Tags: php, foreach

I have a JSON data that looks like this (link for full response here https://pastebin.com/LG2F9Vrw)

`"data": [      {        "matchId": 1653309,        "personId": 1141434,        "teamId": 89736,  "competitors": [          {            "teamCode": "SHC",            "website": "",          }        ]      },`

There's an array of `['data']` that I'm using with foreach to give me game statistics. There's now a second array inside of the `['data']` array. I'mn trying to get the `['teamCode']` string to print but I can't work out how to do it.

I've done my best following tutorials online.

```
<?php foreach($json3['response']['data'] as $item) {
    
print '<tr data-v-7429a5ba="" class="border-b-2 border-gray-accent-100">
       <td data-v-7429a5ba="" class="relative lg:text-sm xxs:text-xs text-center">
       <div data-v-7429a5ba="" class="h-full border-team-'; 
foreach($json3['response']['data']['competitors'] as $row => $value) {
  print $value['teamCode'];
}">';
?>
```

There are other areas where I'm using `print $item['sFieldGoalsPercentage'];` but that's coming under the first foreach.

Thanks!

Comment: what you are posted not a JSON, please show us a valid JSON code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385796/basic-json-syntax

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: TYPO: what is `">';` at the end of the code you showed (just after the closed `}` of foreach) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple code how to retreive `['teamCode']` you want ([test link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11b794f69fdc8f97424bf203028be960fe276e41)):

```
$json3 = json_decode($v,true); // $v is the json code that referred via the link you mentioned
foreach($json3['response']['data'] as $item) {
    echo '<tr data-v-7429a5ba="" class="border-b-2 border-gray-accent-100">
          <td data-v-7429a5ba="" class="relative lg:text-sm xxs:text-xs text-center">';
    foreach ($item["competitors"] as $row){
        echo '<div data-v-7429a5ba="" class="h-full border-team-'.$row["teamCode"].'"></div>';
    }
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

this is the output:

```
<tr data-v-7429a5ba="" class="border-b-2 border-gray-accent-100">
  <td data-v-7429a5ba="" class="relative lg:text-sm xxs:text-xs text-center">
    <div data-v-7429a5ba="" class="h-full border-team-SHC"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr data-v-7429a5ba="" class="border-b-2 border-gray-accent-100">
  <td data-v-7429a5ba="" class="relative lg:text-sm xxs:text-xs text-center">
    <div data-v-7429a5ba="" class="h-full border-team-KBA"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr data-v-7429a5ba="" class="border-b-2 border-gray-accent-100">
  <td data-v-7429a5ba="" class="relative lg:text-sm xxs:text-xs text-center">
    <div data-v-7429a5ba="" class="h-full border-team-HRE"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr data-v-7429a5ba="" class="border-b-2 border-gray-accent-100">
  <td data-v-7429a5ba="" class="relative lg:text-sm xxs:text-xs text-center">
    <div data-v-7429a5ba="" class="h-full border-team-NEW"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr data-v-7429a5ba="" class="border-b-2 border-gray-accent-100">
  <td data-v-7429a5ba="" class="relative lg:text-sm xxs:text-xs text-center">
    <div data-v-7429a5ba="" class="h-full border-team-UHC"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr data-v-7429a5ba="" class="border-b-2 border-gray-accent-100">
  <td data-v-7429a5ba="" class="relative lg:text-sm xxs:text-xs text-center">
    <div data-v-7429a5ba="" class="h-full border-team-SHC"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr data-v-7429a5ba="" class="border-b-2 border-gray-accent-100">
  <td data-v-7429a5ba="" class="relative lg:text-sm xxs:text-xs text-center">
    <div data-v-7429a5ba="" class="h-full border-team-KBA"></div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The output ends up mashing them all together. Your test does this also. Even when using PHP_EOL it displays them as a list and doesn't go down the table updating each part of the code for each array. Does it write all the arrays as one?https://gyazo.com/efdf328bc0a2c08f412be207827836ff

Comment: you want to make each teamCode in class html div ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f8d2b6d8db2eb253640a203c951f6a21 each three digit code should line up with CSS to change the colour of this box but they're mashing up and not going down per array if that makes sense. I thought a bit of visual context could help

Comment: https://gyazo.com/9a83432ace42e3b67e551f09bea2ee7b here's what the code looks like. So each array has a three letter code that corresponds to the CSS formatting here. Hopefully that helps. I can send the full page code if you would like

Comment: @LiamCollins is that what you looking for ? i edit the test link also, check it

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much! Really appreciate the effort that went into this. Cheers!